# unexpected tokan A in json at postion 0?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

web.php Route its my route every thing fine i think butt i cant finde where i have error am find couple of hours

```
Route::post('/admin/edit_new_category', 'Admin@edit_new_category');
```

custom.js file

```
$(document).on('submit','.database_operation',function(){
    var url=$(this).attr('action');
    var data=$(this).serialize();
    $.post(url,data,function(fb){
       var resp = $.parseJSON(fb);
      if(resp.status=='true')
      {
          alert(resp.message);
          setTimeout(function(){
              window.location.href=resp.reload;
          },1000);
      }
    })
    return false;
});
```

AdminController i think here issue plz if any one know help me

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Oex_category;
use Validator;
class Admin extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function exam_category(){
        $data['category']=Oex_category::orderBy('id','desc')->get()->toArray();
        return view('admin.exam_category',$data);
    }
    public function add_new_category(Request $request){
        $validator=validator::make($request->all(),['name'=>'required']);
        if($validator->passes())
        {
            $cat = new Oex_category();
            $cat->name=$request->name;
            $cat->status=1;
            $cat->save();
            $arr=array('status'=>'true','message'=>'success','reload'=>url('admin/exam_categry'));
        }
        else
        {
            $arr=array('status'=>'false','message'=>$validator->errors()->all());
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
    public function delete_category($id)
    {
        $cat = Oex_category::where('id',$id)->get()->first();
        $cat->delete();
        return redirect(url('admin/exam_categry'));
    }
    public function edit_category($id)
    {
        $category = Oex_category::where('id',$id)->get()->first();
        return view('admin.edit_category',['category'=>$category]);
    }
    public function edit_new_category(Request $request)
    {
        print_r($request->all());
    }
}
```

#edit_category.blade.php its my blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title','Dashboard')
@section('content')
    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark"> Edit Category</h1>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active"> Edit Category</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-header -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <!-- Default box -->
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <form action="{{url('admin/edit_new_category')}}"  class="database_operation" >
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Enter Category Name</label>
                                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$category->id}}">
                                                <input type="text"  required="required" value="{{$category->name}}" name="name" placeholder="Enter Category Name" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-body -->

                            <!-- /.card-footer-->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
@endsection
```

error when am update data and inspect element of page i show that error i cant understand am new laravel use

```
VM708:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (custom.js:7)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using laravel, but you are not using the correct laravel way of outputting data. You need to use the `response()` functions.

This line:

```
print_r($request->all())
```

Outputs a php array dump, which your frontend cannot handle. You need to output json, and you need to output a correct response:

```
return response()->json(["data"=>$request->all()]);
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses

Comment: VM777:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 now this error

Comment: Just realized you are outputting the `request` object. Could you try outputting just a simple string: `return response()->json(["data"=>"test"]);`

Comment: Check your browser's Dev tools, network tab. What is the result of request to your script.

Comment: VM800:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've ever gotten the "Unexpected token A" error, it is because the JSON is either not JSON, or it is malformed.

Figure out how to dump the raw response you are getting to the console or a log file. If the problem isn't obvious by looking at it, run it through a JSON validator. Here's one: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Any solution this problem??